# Undefined is not a function with concat

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm rendering two models on a page with backbone and handlebars. I'm trying to concatenate the two models together but the `concat()` function returns `error:Undefined is not a function`.

This is my render function:

```
render: function (eventName) {
     var twitter=this.collection.models[0].toJSON();
     var instagram=this.collection.models[1].toJSON();
     var conc=twitter.concat(instagram);  <--LINE ERROR      
     $(this.el).html(this.template(conc));
     return this;
},
```

Comment: does twitter have any data in it?

Comment: whats the line? If you have troubles, post the error **with** line number and mark the relevant line! Try `console.log(typeof(twitter), twitter);`

Comment: try doing `JSON.parse()` over the `this.collection.models[0].toJSON()` so `JSON.parse(this.collection.models[0].toJSON())`

Comment: object 
Object {id: 256402874, id_str: "256402874", name: "SteFano Langone", screen_name: "Stefano", location: "Los Angeles, CA"…}

Comment: you can't concat objects together... they need to be array `instanceof Array`, try using, `jQuery.extend()` to extend objects

Comment: Why don't you just do `template({ twitter : this.collection.at(0).toJSON(), instagram: ... })` better?

Comment: @No1_Melman: They're strings after calling `toJSON()`.

Comment: OK perfetc it works with jQuery.extend()

Comment: @ElliotBonneville so using `JSON.parse` is exactly what needs to be done in order to get them to arrays.

Comment: @No1_Melman: why bother calling `JSON.parse` if the OP wants objects, not strings? Why not just skip the `toJSON()` call in the first place?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville i don't know exactly what the OP is working with, if the models are just objects then concat using jQuery extend would be the way to go.

Comment: @user1938193 I put the answer down, accept if it was the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From some comments to the original post `this.collection.models[0].toJSON()` returns a string representation of JSON, obviously for transmitting.

In order to get this to a workable state they need to be transformed to an actual JavaScript object.

```
JSON.parse(this.collection.models[0].toJSON())
```

If this returns an object, then you can use `jQuery.extend()` to concatenate the objects.

If it returns an array, then you can use the extension method `.concat()`.

If `this.collection.models[0]` is just an object, then use `jQuery.extend()` on them, no need with `.toJSON()` as Elliot points out, however, if it is anything like `knockoutjs` where the object has observables in, the `toJSON` may be the way to go, to get the pure object.

```
var finalObj = {};
var twitter = this.collection.models[0];
var instagram = this.collection.models[1];
$.extend(finalObj, twitter, instagram);
```

Comment: A Backbone model's [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) returns an Object, not a String. This is the behavior that [`JSON.stringify` expects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior), hence the poor name for the method. `models[0]` should be a Backbone model instance, `$.extend` won't do anything useful with such a thing.